# How to make the program stop asking for the "4-digit number" if the user has already guessed the number, and make the program display "You Win!"

Tags: python-3.x

The code here in all in all fulfills its purpose, except that I cannot get the code to end and print "You Win!" after all four numbers have been guesses. We have tried using break statements, switching "ifs" with "whiles" and "elifs" as well as changing variables

```
import random
#Gets 4 random single digits to be guesses
n1 = random.randint (0,9)
n2 = random.randint (0,9)
n3 = random.randint (0,9)
n4 = random.randint (0,9)

wrong_guesses = 0

print ("I'm thinking of a 4-digit code. Guess what it is!")
print ("X = wrong guess, O = right guess")

guess = int(input("Enter your 4-number digit here:"))

#Guesses the first (leftmost) number
if guess // 1000 % 10 != n1:
    wrong_guesses +=1
    print ('X')
else:
    wrong_guesses +=0   
    print ('O')
#Guesses the second (second from the left) number
if guess // 100 % 10 != n2:
    wrong_guesses +=1
    print ('X')
else:
    wrong_guesses +=0 
    print ('O')
#Guesses the third (second from right) number
if guess // 10 % 10 != n3:
    wrong_guesses +=1
    print ('X')
else:
    wrong_guesses +=0 
    print ('O')

#Guesses the last (rightmost) number
if guess // 1 % 10 != n4:
    wrong_guesses +=1
    print ('X')
else:
    wrong_guesses +=0 
    print ('O')
if wrong_guesses == 0:
    print ("You win!")
while wrong_guesses != 0:
    guess = int(input("Enter your 4-digit code here:"))
   #Display O if number is correct, X if otherwise
if guess // 1000 % 10 != n1:
    wrong_guesses +=1
    print ('X')
else:
    wrong_guesses +=0 
    print ('O')
if guess // 100 % 10 != n2:
    wrong_guesses +=1
    print ('X')
else:
    wrong_guesses +=0 
    print ('O')
if guess // 10 % 10 != n3:
    wrong_guesses +=1
    print ('X')
else:
    wrong_guesses +=0 
    print ('O')
if guess // 1 % 10 != n4:
    wrong_guesses +=1
    print ('X')
else:
    wrong_guesses +=0 
    print ('O')
if guess == n1 and guess == n2 and guess == n3 and guess == n4:
 print ("You win!")
```

Here is the part where the code fails to end. Instead of displaying validation of a right answer, the code just keeps on asking for more numbers, evem if the numbers were already guessed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to create an [mcve] and then [edit] your question for a better overview.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies when you write :

```
while wrong_guesses != 0:
    guess = int(input("Enter your 4-digit code here:"))
```

Since you have no way to change wrong_guesses value in your loop, you're entering an infinite loop.

I'd try to verify it by throwing some debug print in this loop, to see if this is the case.

Plus, don't "try using break statements, switching "ifs" with "whiles" and "elifs" as well as changing variables" without understanding what you are doing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `wrong_guesses+=0` is both meaningless and cluttering up the code.